# System.Windows.Forms.TreeView Node "not clickable"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I've got a System.Windows.Forms.TreeView with HotTracking = True 
I wish to set HotTracking to False only in a specific Node.

For example i would like the father to be not clickable and the children to be clickable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Clickable" is pretty ambiguous.  I'll assume you don't want them to be selectable.  Which is easy to do with the BeforeSelect event, you can cancel it.  For example:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeSelect
    If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This does not make for a great user interface, the user will be very confuzzled when his click has no effect.  You can make it a bit more intuitive by not throwing the click away and automatically selecting a node that you do allow to be selected.  Make that look similar to this:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeSelect
    If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of TreeNode)(AddressOf SelectNode), e.Node.Nodes(0))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SelectNode(ByVal node As TreeNode)
    node.Expand()
    node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node
End Sub
```